# Another Image Gallery in HTML, CSS and JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'am trying to make another image gallery using HTML, CSS and JQuery. The problem is that when I press the R button (stands for RIGHT) the picture moves only that time, after that the R button doesn't work unless you use the L button to go to the left. I've been trying to fix it but I simply can't get it to work. I think the problem is  that the value of `.index()` doesn't increment as I press the R button, but I don't know how to fix it because I'm still new to JQuery. And also If you press the R button on any picture except the first two, the R button takes you to the second picture.

This is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
     $('#slide1_controls').on('click', 'span', function(){
         $("#slide1_images").css("transform","translateX("+$(this).index() * -600+"px)");
         $("#slide1_controls span").removeClass("selected");
         $(this).addClass("selected");
     });
 }); 
$(document).ready(function() { 
     $('#right').click(function(){
         $("#slide1_images").css("transform","translateX("+ $(this).index() * -600+"px)");
         
     });
});

$(document).ready(function() { 
     $('#left').click(function(){
         $("#slide1_images").css("transform","translateX("+$(this).index() * 600+"px)");
     });
});
```

```css
#slide1_container {
  width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#slide1_images {
  width: 3000px; /* (width * image number) */
  -webkit-transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
}
#slide1_images img {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}
#slide1_controls {
  margin-left: 12%;
}
span img {
  width: 17%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slide1_container" class="shadow">
        <div id="slide1_images">
          <img class="img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature.jpg">
          <img class="img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg">
          <img class="img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains.jpg">
          <img class="img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature.jpg">
          <img class="img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
      <p id="slide1_controls">
        <span class="selected">
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature.jpg">
        </span> 
        <span>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg">
        </span> 
        <span>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains.jpg">
        </span> 
        <span>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature.jpg">
        </span> 
        <span>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg">
        </span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <a  id="left">L</a> | <a id="right">R</a>
      </p>
```

Comment: `$(this).index()` is always going to be the same for `#left` and `#right`. It works when you click on the thumbnails because each thumbnail has it's own unique index.

Comment: 'I think the problem is that the value of .index() doesn't increment as I press the R button, but I don't know how to fix it because I'm still new to JQuery.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look, the problem is here:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     $('#right').click(function(){
         $("#slide1_images").css("transform","translateX("+ $(this).index() * -600+"px)");

     });
});
```

Your **this**, which you want to use to point to the index of the current item actually doesn't point to slide in the slideshow, in this function it points to the 'Right' link you're clicking on. Just try to add console.log **this** and to click to the button:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     $('#right').click(function(){
         $("#slide1_images").css("transform","translateX("+ $(this).index() * -600+"px)");

       console.log(this);

     });
});
```

**this** in JS is a bit tricky, yes =)

So if you want to make it slideable, you need to point to the actual slide index:

Now check please the [fixed example I've added to the Codepen](https://codepen.io/nat-davydova/pen/xvEbLK):

- Here I've invented a variable indexCurrent to save an index of the current slide, by default it's equal to 0;
- Every time we click on the Right button we increase an index to the 1 and we translate the whole slider container;
- The same if we click on the Left btn, but now we decrease an index;

My example is not really perfect but I hope it will help you. If you have any questions don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: The thing is that I tried to put the slide value in a variable but the value of the variable wouldn't change as I incremented it on every slide. Anyway thank you, this is the answer I was looking for.